# Create and use constants in laravel 5.5

Tags: constants, laravel-5.5

i am using laravel 5.5 and want to create constants and use in my controller and view . i use a code but it's not working. Please help me

i create a file app/config/constant.php and call the constant

```
echo config('constant.myVariable');
```

Comment: 'not working' - what is the actual result and what is the result you expect?

Comment: I want to set my constant value fetch from database as I declare in cakephp appController and I want to use it in my all controller and view as like cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in config.

```
# file named config/foo.php
    <?php

    return [
        'bar' => 'baz',
    ];
```

Then you can output the value of `bar` in this way:

```
Config::get('foo.bar');
```

Comment: i also use this syntex
echo Config::get('constant.myVariable');

but it also not working

Comment: <?php

return array(
    'myVariable' => 'baz',
);

Answer (score 0):

May be this is helpful to you.

add line on top

use App\config;

then try to call

echo config('constant.myVariable');

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 -** Create `constants.php` in `config/` folder(In which all config files are present. `auth`, `database` etc.).

**Step 2 -** Define constants in `key => value` pair in that file,

```
return[
    'userAuthKey' => '21991325b1e2a4f',
    'userName' => 'dummy' 
];
```

**Step 3 -** Close `php artisan serve'`

**Step 4 -** Run command, `php artisan config:cache`

**Step 5 -** Run command. `php artisan serve`

**Step 6 -** Get value of spacific variable,

```
$auth = config('constants.userAuthKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create constant file for Laravel 5.5

1) Create **constants.php** file in the **config folder**.
The constants.php file will look like -

```
<?php

return [

    'name' => 'Stack Overflow',

];
```

2) Access it anywhere in the following way -

```
config('constants.name')
```

The above-mentioned call will contain your constant value.